# Is Tube light polychromatic?

Tags: visible-light

Is tube light/fluorescent lamp monochromatic or polychromatic? Please justify.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the plots of spectra of different fluorescent lamps as given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp#Phosphor_composition), you can definitely say: yes, it's certainly polychromatic.

Moreover, true monochromatic light is an abstraction, which can't be implemented in a real device, because it's the light infinite in time - from infinite past to infinite future. It is a limit, which can be approached instead. One of the most monochromatic light source is [laser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser). Even better one is the filtered output of certain electron transitions. Such devices are used to e.g. define [unit of distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#Standard_wavelength_of_krypton-86_emission).

Comment: Well, to be nitpicky, the most monochromatic device is the filtered output of certain electron transitions, as once use used in the definition of distance:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#Standard_wavelength_of_krypton-86_emission

Comment: @CarlWitthoft can't $^{86} \text{Kr}$ be made one of active gases of a gas laser? ;)

Comment: Yes it probably could, but then you run into Lamb dips,  pressure broadening, and all the other stuff that happens in any gas laser.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks, I've edited my answer to include your device.